# How to disable and/or enable some activity on configurations. Android

Tags: android, configuration

I want to make an app that there is levels. When I set level 1 for example in my configuration, I want just Activity1 enabled and others  disabled. And when I set level 2 on my configuration, I want that enable acitivty1 and acitivty2 and disable activity3 for example.

I dont know if I was clear.

I don't have any code yet, I just have my idea to make my code. But I don't know how to disable on my configuration page the Activity that I want

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you just pass an Intent. Like there are 2 or 3 buttons. when you press the button it just pass an Intent and navigate from one class to another

Comment: @Hasan I want that just in configuration i can define which activity the user will be able to use. It will be for kids, and i want that parents set in conf. I don't know if  that's what you asked

Comment: Now I am little bit confused. What do you mean by levels??

Comment: @Hasan My app is for children. I want to show firstly (like level 1, defined by parents) one activity with direct action, for example: "Water". Then, when the kid is more advanced opens 2 activitys, defined by parents on configuration, for example: 1st activity "drink" and opens the second with image "water". So, we have formed "drink water". And at last, when defined to show all three activity, for example: 1st activity "I want to" second "drink", third "water". It is a little complicated to explain... :(